# Laravel Excel Não entendo o que está sendo preenchido

Tags: laravel, microsoft-excel

Eu não entendo o que está acontecendo neste código que preenche uma a celula B8 no excel:

```
$sheet->cell('BQ'.$i, function($cell) use($report) {
    $cell->setValue(!empty($report->PastaStatusHistorical->where('status_historical.status','Concluído')->first()) ?
    $report->PastaStatusHistorical->where('status_historical.status','Concluído')->first()->created_at->format('d/m/Y') : '');
});
```

Está sendo passada uma data do banco de dados ou da aplicação?

Como acho essa tabela e coluna no banco?

Esse `where->` indica que está havendo um select?

`created_at->` é um método?

O que está acontecendo com `PastaStatusHistorical`? Eu vou no modelo e não acho esses campos de status 'concluido'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa entender que esse tipo de consulta é feita usando o Eloquent, ele é uma implantação de ActiveRecord pra trabalhar com a base de dados, a documentação completa está disponível disponível [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent),

Vou começar formatando o código sem o uso do operador Ternário, para trechos de códigos maiores eu prefiro usar o `if / else` por uma questão de legibilidade.

```
$sheet->cell('BQ'.$i, function($cell) use($report) {

    if(!empty($report->PastaStatusHistorical->where('status_historical.status','Concluído')->first()) {

        $valor = $report->PastaStatusHistorical->where('status_historical.status','Concluído')->first()->created_at->format('d/m/Y');

    } else {

        $valor = '';

    }

    $cell->setValue($valor);

});
```

As colunas `created_at` e `updated_at` são colunas gerenciadas automaticamente pelo [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#defining-models), elas não precisam ser referenciadas no modelo, basicamente quando um registro for criado, o horário atual do servidor será cadastrado na coluna `created_at`, e quando acontecer uma atualização nessa linha o campo `updated_at` será atualizado.

Sim, o `where` indica que está sendo feita uma consulta, e o `first()` define que apenas a primeira linha encontrada deve ser retornada.

O `PastaStatusHistorical` é uma [relação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) de tabelas definida no modelo, o `hasMany` é uma relação **1 : N**, se você entender inglês sugiro ler a documentação oficial, se não encontrei esse [artigo](https://medium.com/trainingcenter/relacionando-models-e-tabelas-no-laravel-5-4-a8365a12eca2) em português.

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora no model ta essa jossa aqui :  public function PastaStatusHistorical(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\StatusHistoricalFolder', 'pasta_id');
 }                              // nao consegui deixar como codigo ... pode me explicar o que está acontecendo ?? ainda tenho que ir atras desse status historical folder, que é um outro model pra entender o que está acontecendo ?? ooo inferno, esse laravel veio pra facilitar a vida de alguem ??

Comment: @VictorHugo, editei a resposta com um artigo em português sobre o relacionamento entre tabelas, e sobre o Laravel ajudar, acho q ele ajuda muito, uma vez que você entenda o **Eloquent ORM**, dificilmente você vai precisar escrever algum código código SQL, e fazendo os relacionamentos corretos, você nunca mais vai fazer `INNER JOIN` nas suas consultas.